# mysql join 2 user_ids in a row from users table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

There are 2 tables:

```
orders:
id   requester_id   supplyer_id  status
1    423            1           reserved
2    500            1           supplied
3    222            2           reserved
...

users
id    username  register_date
1     admin     2012-01-01
2     smith     2013-01-01
...
423   John      2012-10-11
500   Doe       2012-12-11
222   name      2012-10-13 
...
```

I want to join these two tables and get this as a result

```
id  requester_username   supplier_username  status
1   John                 admin              reserved
2   Doe                  admin              supplied
3   name                 smith              reserved
```

I can actually join these tables using active records like :

```
$this->db->select('orders.*,users.username')
   ->from('orders')
   ->join('users','users.id = orders.requester_id')
   ->get()->result();
```

but I dont know how to get the `supplier username` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a second JOIN:

```
$this->db->select('orders.*,requesters.username,suppliers.username')
   ->from('orders')
   ->join('users AS requesters', 'requesters.id = orders.requester_id')
   ->join('users AS suppliers',  'suppliers.id  = orders.supplier_id')
   ->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql Your query should be like -

```
Select a.id, b.username, c.username, a.status
from orders a, users b, users c
where
a.requester_id = b.id 
And
a.supplyer_id = c.id
```

Thanks